# Is using compose to add routes and middleware to an Express app an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, functional-programming

I am working on a small server that will eventually be used as a boilerplate for future servers. Since order can matter for middleware, I  reached for compose to pipe them all together in an obvious order. My goal is to add one level of abstraction for the middleware and routes so they can be swapped out later without too many changes to the entry point.

Given this info, does it seem like an anti-pattern to use `compose` since the middleware/routes themselves are impure and modify the `(app)` that gets passed in?

```
'use strict';

import { createServer } from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import { flowRight as compose } from 'lodash';

import { system, environment } from './config';
import routes from './routes';

const setup = compose(routes, system);
const app = setup(express());

createServer(app)
    .listen(environment.port, environment.ip, () => {
        console.log('Server running!');
    });
```

Comment: pure functions are not a requirement for function composition

Comment: @naomik True, I just haven't seen this pattern used to set up Express, although it seems like a a good use case.